# How to count the total amount of similar rows in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I need help with a MySQL query to count the number of times a combination of the same age_from and age_to occur.

Sample data:

```
 age_from   age_to
+---------+-------+
  18      |   100
  30      |   75
  18      |   50
  18      |   100
  30      |   75
  18      |   50
  30      |   75
+---------+------+
```

Desired result:

```
18 to 100 = 2
30 to 75 = 3
18 to 50 = 2
```

I have already tried this:

```
SELECT
`p_age_from` AS `age_from`,
`p_age_to` AS `age_to`,
COUNT(`p_age_from`) AS `user_count`
FROM `user`
GROUP BY `p_age_from`, `p_age_to`
ORDER BY `p_age_from`
```

Comment: You could use UNION

Comment: What's wrong with your query? It works for me, except the ordering is different: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iNxrhbCqGpzMwYBhoHRvos/0

Comment: To get the ording you want, use `ORDER BY p_age_to DESC`

Answer (score 2):

You can use CONCAT to join the **age_from** and **age_to** values. Then use this to group and count the data:

```
SELECT
CONCAT(`age_from`,' to ',`age_to`) as 'grouping',
COUNT('grouping') AS `user_count`
FROM `user`
GROUP BY grouping
```

Comment: I hadn't ever tried using this kind of "concatenated string as a group" grouping before, so tried it out - here's the SQLFiddle, just in case it's useful for anyone else http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/606f62/5

Answer (score 0):

You can get your result using following query

SELECT CONCAT(age_from,' to ',age_to,' = ',count(age_to)) as 'age_from to  age_to'
 FROM user
 GROUP BY age_from, age_to
 ORDER BY age_from;